# Can background assets in SwiftUI be implemented for lower version ios such as ios 14.0. If yes then how?

Tags: swiftui, background-assets-framework

I want to know if we can use background assests in swiftUI for ios versions lower than ios 16.0 such as ios 14.0. If yes what changes we have to make to do so?

I researched on the topic of background assests in SwiftUI a bit and found out it is available for ios 16.0 version and beyond. Is there a way to do it for lower version ios.

Comment: I am not sure this is doable. Without the Background Assets framework, you have no ability to run code upon installation to perform the downloads.

Comment: The Background Assets framework [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundassets) explicitly states support for “iOS 16+”, so, no, it is not supported in earlier versions.